# Controlling dropdown list items with jquery if statement

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown list that includes personel names, when I select personel, It displays informations about personels. I need to add a statement in my codes that don't brings one more time the personel I already selected, here my codes:

```
$(function() {
  var ids = [{{personel.pk}}]
  $(".pers").click(function() {
    pk = this.getAttribute('data-pk');
    url = '/post/' + pk + '/personel_ajax/';
    resp = '<div class="row">';
    resp += $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('success', data);
        console.log(data);
        $('#container').append(
          '<div class="col-sm-4">' +
          '  <div class="thumbnail">' +
          '    <div class="caption">' +
          '      <h3>' + data[0]['fields']['name'] + ' <small>{{post.date}}</small></h3>' +
          '      <p>' + data[0]['fields']['title'] + '</p>' +
          '      <p>' + data[0]['fields']['title2'] + '</p>' +
          '      <p><a href="/post/' + data[0]['pk'] + '/" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Task Description</a>' +
          '        <a href="/post/'+data[0]['pk'] + '/update" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" role="button">Update Task</a>' +
          '        <a href="/post/'+data[0]['pk'] + '/delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete Task</a></p>' +
          '    </div>' +
          '  </div>' +
          '</div>'
        );
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple array as simple cache;

```
$(function() {
  var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var dataCache = [];
  var pk;
  function render(data) {
    $("#container").append(
      '<div class="col-sm-4">' +
        '<div class="thumbnail">' +
        '<div class="caption">' +
        "<h3>" +
        data[0].fields.name +
        " <small>{{post.date}}</small></h3>" +
        "<p>" +
        data[0].fields.title +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>" +
        data[0].fields.title2 +
        "</p>" +
        '<p><a href="/post/' +
        data[0].pk +
        '/" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Task Description</a>' +
        '<a href="/post/' +
        data[0].pk +
        '/update" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" role="button">Update Task</a>' +
        '<a href="/post/' +
        data[0].pk +
        '/delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">Delete Task</a></p>' +
        "</div>" +
        "</div>"
    );
  }

  $(".pers").click(function() {
    pk = this.getAttribute("data-pk");
    url = "/post/" + pk + "/personel_ajax/";
    resp = '<div class="row">';
    if (dataCache[pk]) {
      render(dataCache[pk]);
      return;
    }
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("success", data);
        console.log(data);
        dataCache[pk] = data;
        render(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```